# how to test a mobile site in multiple devices parallelly?

Tags: mobile

We need to test a web site in different devices in defferent OS. I found many tools to the url in multiple devices but couldn't found anything which can be used to test the UI in different devices at one by operating the site in a single device(or emulator). Please help us.

Answer (score 0):

[Test your website on any screen size i.e different devices](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

[Test your website on various browser](http://browsershots.org/)